# Dimension of the quotient space $\frac{C_{0}}{M}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $C_{0}=\{(x_{n}):x_{n}\in\mathbb{R},x_{n}\rightarrow 0\}$ and $M=\{(x_{n})\in C_{0}:x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+x_{10}=0\}.$ I have to find dimension of the space $\frac{C_{0}}{M}.$ According to me its dimension is infinite. But i am not correct. Please tell me what is the exact dimension of the quotient space and how to find it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map

$$C_0 \to \mathbb R, (x_n) \mapsto x_1+x_2 + \dotsb + x_{10}.$$

It is surjective (you can always choose the first $10$ elements of the sequence as you desire, without changing the limit) and the kernel is $M$ by definition. Hence $C_0/M \cong \mathbb R$.

Comment: yes i got the point....thanks a lot for your precise time....